# How to remove the last N rows on a dataset based on ID in R?

Tags: r, subset

How do I go from a dataframe like this:

| ID | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 6 |
| 1 | 6 | 5 |
| 1 | 8 | 4 |
| 1 | 9 | 6 |
| 2 | 6 | 4 |
| 2 | 7 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 9 |

to this:

| ID | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 6 |
| 1 | 6 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 | 4 |

In this example, I wanted to remove the last 2 rows for every ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(between(row_number(), 1, n()-2))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID     X     Y
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     4     6
2     1     6     5
3     2     6     4
```

Or this one:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(1:(n()-2))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID     X     Y
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     4     6
2     1     6     5
3     2     6     4
```

Answer (score 3):

An option with `head` used within `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   slice(head(row_number(), -2)) %>% 
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     ID     X     Y
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     4     6
2     1     6     5
3     2     6     4
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), X = c(4L, 
6L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 3L), Y = c(6L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 9L)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(row_number() <= n()-2)
```

Output:

```
     ID     X     Y
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     4     6
2     1     6     5
3     2     6     4
```